# An unexpected version directory while using pod repo lint

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I can't fix problem with cocoapods. I'm trying to create private repo with some library. When I'm executing

```
pod repo lint MyLib --verbose
```

I'm getting error:

> An unexpected version directory `AppIcon.appiconset` was encountered
>   for the `MyLib/Images.xcassets` Pod in the `Images.xcassets`
>   repository.

I dig google for solutions for it, but only hints was to update cocaPods. At this moment I've newest version but still no clue how to move forward.
Any ideas what to check?

Comment: did you get any answer to this?

Answer (score 7):

You lost the extension.

> pod repo lint MyLib.podspec